# Check Jar signer

Tags: java, jar

I wrote a Java program and packed into a runnable jar. Then, I signed the jar.
**How can the jar check by it self was signed by me? And ensure the jar was not changed by others.**
I want to add some code into the main class of the jar to check the jar, instead of using jarsigner or other external tools.

Answer (score 1):

i assume that you want to protect your code programmaticly.
there is an another way to protect your java code. 
if i were you, i would look for open source java obfuscators on internet.
Here would be a starting point for you:

http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators

Answer (score 0):

Verifying the class signatures is usually the job of the [ClassLoader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). You would have to implement your own ClassLoader which checks the code signature before loading it. A nice (but complex) example can be found [O'Reilly's Java Security book](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/ch12_02.htm#SEC-CH-12-SECT-2.1).